# Why does FB.Feed report always return "cancelled"=true on android/ios?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Im in the progress of integrating Facebook in my unity project (using the official Facebook unity SDK beta 6.2). Im on unity 4.5.5p5.

I´m using FB.Feed to show a post on my wall, and it all works as it should. Im using the FBreport from my post to do stuff depending if the user do a post or not. This block of code works as expected on desktop, but it gives me another result on android and IOS. My problem is that the FBReport always returns "cancelled\":true", even if I actually do a post on my wall. Here my code:

```
     FB.Feed
(
linkDescription: "Test!",
picture: "http://www.link.com/picture.png",
linkName: "link",
link: "http://www.url.com",
linkCaption: "Caption",
callback: ShareCallback
);
}
void ShareCallback(FBResult shareResult)
{
if (shareResult.Error != null || shareResult.Text.Contains("\"cancelled\":true"))
{
// This block runs on desktop if user abort post, but on android and ios this runs every time, even when post is successful.
}
else
{
//This part runs on desktop if user posts, but never on android and ios.
}
```

The post gets through, and shows up on my wall, but it seems to be something weird in the FBReport on android/ios.

Im using FB.Apprequest to send invites to my game, and using the same method to get status of post. In FB.Apprequest everything works, both on android, desktop and ios. Anyone who knows how to solve or get around this problem?

Comment: Update: This is a confirmed bug from facebook. The report works as expected if you uninstall the officiall facebook app from your device.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in their SDK for Unity: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598200610227965/

There is a workaround, you can change the DialogMode in the FbUnityInterface.mm

From this

```
self.dialogMode = NativeDialogModes::FAST_APP_SWITCH_SHARE_DIALOG;
```

To this

```
self.dialogMode = NativeDialogModes::WEBVIEW_DIALOG_MODE;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. This is a great workaround for ios. But how about android? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On Android, to show the Webview dialog instead of using the Facebook app, I came up with the following hack:

1. Export Unity project to "Google Android Project"
2. Open the exported project file FacebookDialog.java (com.facebook.widget)
3. Modify the method `canPresentShareDialog(...)` to always return FALSE

With this modification, when Facebook tries to launch the share dialog (FB.java method `FeedRequest()`), it will always think there is no Facebook app installed. I just figured this out today, but so far I haven't noticed any other Facebook functionality breaking.

Answer (score 0):

This solution was also mentioned this fix in the original bug report ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598200610227965/)). We use this solution in our project.

In `AndroidFacebook.cs` add the following code in the beginning of the `FeedRequest` method (right after paramsDict is initialized):

```
// Fix for the FB share bug: 
// https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/598200610227965/ 
// This is an "unsupported" parameter that 
// will force the FB jar to use the web version of the share dialog.
paramsDict.Add("dummy", 1);
```